# How to show ${\rm tr}[AXA'] \geq {\rm tr}[X]$ for $X\geq 0$ if $AA' \geq I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, trace

Assume that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $AA' \geq I_n$, where $A'$ is the transpose of $A$, and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $X \geq 0$, i.e., $X$ is a positive matrix
.
How to show
\begin{equation}
{\rm tr}[AXA'] \geq {\rm tr}[X],
\end{equation}
where ${\rm tr}[X]$ is the trace of $X$, i.e., ${\rm tr}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{ii}$.

Comment: Hint: use $X=C'C$ and $\operatorname{tr}(MN)=\operatorname{tr}(NM)$.

Comment: You want to prove $X_{jk}\ge0\land A_{ij}A_{ik}\ge\delta_{jk}\implies A_{ij}A_{ik}X_{jk}\ge\delta_{jk}X_{jk}$, where each $\ge$ is suitably interpreted. You should start from these interpretations. @A.T.'s strategy probably works, although we want to prove a constraint on $AA^\prime$ implies a constraint on $A^\prime A$.

Comment: Does your notation $X \geq 0$ mean that $X$ is nonnegative or that $X$ is PSD?

Comment: Here $X$ is  PSD.

Comment: Thank your help. @J.G.

Comment: Thank your help. @A.Γ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define matrix $ M = \begin{bmatrix}
   I_n & -A \\ A' & I_n
  \end{bmatrix} $, since $ I_n $ is invertible, thus we have
\begin{equation}
  \det[M] = \det[I_n] \det[I_n - A'I_n^{-1}(-A)] = \det[I_n +A'A].
 \end{equation}
On the other hands, we have
\begin{equation}
  \det[M] = \det[I_n] \det[I_n - (-A)I_n^{-1}A'] = \det[I_n +AA'],
 \end{equation}
thus there must be that $ \det[I_n +A'A] =  \det[I_n +AA']$.
Let $ \lambda \neq 0 $, then we have
\begin{equation}\label{key}
  \det[AA' - \lambda I_n] = (-\lambda)^n \det[\frac{AA'}{\lambda}+I_n] = (-\lambda)^n \det[\frac{A'A}{\lambda}+I_n] = \det[A'A - \lambda I_n],
 \end{equation}
this means that $ AA' $ and $ A'A $ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Note that $ AA' \geq I_n $, thus we have $ A'A \geq I_n $. Since $ X \geq 0 $, there exists matrix $ D $ such that $ X = DD' $.
Further, it follows that
\begin{equation}
  {\rm tr}[AXA'] = {\rm tr}[ADD'A'] = {\rm tr}[D'A'AD]  
  \geq {\rm tr}[D'I_n D] ={\rm tr}[X].
 \end{equation}

Comment: The thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019343/definition-of-spectral-radius-%2F-eigenvalues-of-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-complex-conjugate-transpose#comment-2080933 has a more direct way to prove  that $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ has the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Maybe more straightforward: $AA'\ge I$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $I\ge A^{-1}(A^{-1})'$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\|(A^{-1})'\|\le 1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\|A^{-1}\|\le 1$ etc to $A'A\ge I$.